# Xamarin iOS VPN app extension not starting packet tunnel provider class

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, vpn

I am developing a VPN app for iOS using Xamarin. As per iOS docs there needs to be an app extension which would finally connect VPN to a remote server.

**Question 1.** Can I create an app extension supporting 'Packet Tunnel' in Xamarin on Mac OS X using Visual Studio code. When I try to create an app extension in the wizard there is no VPN extension option. I created an Action Sheet extension and manually modified **Info.plist** and **Entitlement.plist** file to support VPN a *hack*.

With above changes I was able to create an app extension and was able to deploy on a real device. ow the main iOS app was able to save VPN profile and I could see it in settings. My current app extension tunnel provider *class is empty* I just have simple log lines.

**Question 2.** I was expecting I would get some logs and it would eventually fail as there is no code, but my class is never called. There is no stacktrace. Only thing I could extract from console connecting to real device is as follows.

```
Unhandled Exception:
Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown. Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: *** -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:]: object cannot be nil (key: 7E3DD3B9-285A-4EB1-9DCA-6EC5B89214DA)
Native stack trace:
    0  CoreFoundation           0x00000001b130a9a4 <redacted> + 252
    1  libobjc.A.dylib           0x00000001b04e39f8 objc_exception_throw + 56
    2  CoreFoundation           0x00000001b12843f8 _CFArgv + 0
    3  CoreFoundation           0x00000001b11f9228 <redacted> + 940
    4  Foundation             0x00000001b1d288b4 <redacted> + 100
    5  Foundation             0x00000001b1d28124 <redacted> + 764
    6  libdispatch.dylib          0x00000001b0d48a38 <redacted> + 24
    7  libdispatch.dylib          0x00000001b0d497d4 <redacted> + 16
    8  libdispatch.dylib          0x00000001b0cf2324 <redacted> + 592
    9  libdispatch.dylib          0x00000001b0cf2e40 <redacte<…>
```

I am starting tunnel as follows. The below code is inside **NETunnelProviderManager.LoadAllFromPreferences** completion handler.

```
var activationAttemptId = new NSUuid().AsString() + "-SECRET-VPN";
Console.WriteLine("Activation UUID " + activationAttemptId);
var options = new NSDictionary<NSString, NSObject>((NSString)NSObject.FromObject("activationAttemptId"), NSObject.FromObject(activationAttemptId));
var sessionConnection = tunnelProviderManager.Connection as NETunnelProviderSession;

NSError terror;

sessionConnection.StartTunnel(options, out terror);

if (terror != null && terror.Code != null)
{
       Console.Error.WriteLine("While starting VPN error ...." + terror.Code);
}
```

My configuration saving code is as follows.

```
var tunnelProviderManager = new NETunnelProviderManager();
tunnelProviderManager.LocalizedDescription = "Second Xam VPN";
                    

var protocolConfiguration = new NETunnelProviderProtocol();
protocolConfiguration.ProviderBundleIdentifier = "xxx.xxx";
protocolConfiguration.ServerAddress = "XXX:XXX";
protocolConfiguration.ProviderConfiguration = new NSDictionary<NSString, NSObject>();

tunnelProviderManager.ProtocolConfiguration = protocolConfiguration;

tunnelProviderManager.Enabled = true;

tunnelProviderManager.SaveToPreferences((NSError error) => {// ...logic here .....});
```

I'll really appreciate If some guidance is provided how to tackle the issue may be some debug help, I have intermediate skills with Xamarin and overall mobile development.

Both apps and apps extension **Info.plist** and **Entitlement.plist** have correct entitlements.

One thing would like to share Visual Studio for Mac 2019 adds incorrect entitlement when graphical editor is used. It adds value for key **com.apple.developer.networking.networkextension** as **packet-tunnel** instead of **packet-tunnel-provider**.

Comment: For fun, did you try add a try/catch around your code?

Comment: @Cheesebaron yes there is no exception in Visual Studio output from device section, but if I connect via console I see some activity with exception as in post.

Answer (score 1):

Two issues.

1. I still do not agree the value for key **com.apple.developer.networking.networkextension** is **packet-tunnel**. You cannot deploy to a real device with that value. Even you download provisional certificate from Apple developer website with which you are signing and open it in text editor though it is a binary file, it clearly states the value as **packet-tunnel-provider**, how come then **packet-tunnel** works is a mystery to me. *I lost 2 weeks for it.*
2. As I mentioned I changed 'Action Sheet' extension to 'Network Extension', during the convert process I missed adding **[Register]** annotation on my **PacketTunnelProvider** class that I registered as the class supporting extension code. Probably NSDictionary nil error was related to it, not sure.

Now extension class is called, constructor and StartTunnel method is called and I can see logs in console app still not in 'Application Output', may be it will show logs for main app only.

Answer (score 0):

#### Question 1

We could enable the `Network Extensions` option in `Entitlements.plist` in graphical  way , and check the string as source way , it should be `packet-tunnel` not anything else .

[image]

[image]

---

#### Question 2

I test with your code , it works fine , I can't be able to reproduce the error , it seems no problem with your code .

---

#### Others

When testing on a real device , we should use the certificate and profile which enables `Network Extensions` as well , we need to do that on [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/) , download the files and set them in project .

Comment: If I use packet-tunnel it fails to deploy on device. I checked my profile provision, app id is wildcard *, it has network extension and data protection capability. The device on which I am trying to deploy is mapped and my developer certificate.